# Backbone.js: How to model an entity with two representations

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm new to backbone.js so bear with me. I'd like to find out what is the best scenario to model the following:

I have a 'Car' item which has two presentations that should be linked to the same 'Car' object. The first representation is a car div that shows the actual car (e.g. red car with green wheels). The second representation is the create/edit dialog for the car in which the user can change the car's attributes.

Do I need to create two Views and one ViewController for this scenario, do I need two ViewControllers, or should I only have one View and one Controller and two separate render methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no ViewControllers in backbone. You will want:

- one `Backbone.Model` subclass for the car
- one `Backbone.View` subclass & one template for the read-only view of the car
- one `Backbone.View` subclass & one template for the create/edit dialog